# proving that $a^6 \in L$ (tricky) (pumping lemma)

Tags: computer-science, automata

i've encountered a quite tricky question that i don't understand, and would appreciate your help with:

it is said that by the pumping lemma, for a certain L there exists(guarenteed) n=2. also known that $aa \in L$. prove that $a^6 \in L$

so from what i understand, because it is guranteed that for some L, because of the pumping lemma, n=2, it means that for a word $w \in L$, w can be represented as such: w=abc, so that $|ab| \leq n$, $|b| \geq 1$ and for every $i \in N$: $ab^ic \in L$. so if $aa \in L$, then the boundary(first condition) is n=2 as given, but does it mean that it can only one letter, so that $a^6 \in L$? basically, i think that i should be using the third condition(for every $i \in N$ $ab^ic \in L$, but how can i ommit a and c so i could show that i=6, i.e $a^6 \in L$

tried to explain the question and my way of thinking the best i could. how can i show that $a^6 \in L$?

Comment: Think of what $b$ can be in your situation for the word $aa$. Remember that if $n=2$ is the pumping constant, the word $aa$ satisfies the initial conditions to be pumped.

Comment: i might be very confused, but b should be a? really confused and would appreciate your help with it

Answer (score 1):

Ok, let's fix some easier notation:

We say that a language $L$ satisfies the pumping lemma for $p>0$ if for any word $w\in L$ with $|w|\geq p$ we have that $w=xyz$ with the properties:
$$1. p\geq |xy|, |y|>0
$$
$$2. \forall i\in \Bbb N: xy^iz\in L
$$
So in our case, $y$ (which is being 'pumped') would either be $a$ or $aa$.

Comment: so basically after asserting that y is either a or aa, is it sufficient to say that because of this and the properties of the pumping lemma, $a^6 \in L$?

Comment: Yes, and you can divide to cases and prove it directly if you want to.